# Python program to download SRTM and cut shape file

Tags: python, shapefile, srtm

Hi I want to create a python program with graphic interface who takes in entry coordinates and download srtm and cut shape file of this area. Please if possible give me complet program with comments. Thanks in advance

I am beginner. Just want to learn